# EXECUTE AS user/login for a group

Tags: sql-server

I've seen many an article stating the fact that you cannot EXECUTE AS {user/login} for a group login; however, none of those really had any good ideas on how to test permissions on a group. If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to test permissions on a group

Grant all your permissions through Roles, then you can test using a regular user who is in all the same roles.  eg

```
create role AppUsers
create user AppUser without login
alter role AppUsers add member AppUser 

alter role AppUsers add member [BUILTIN\Administrators]
```

Comment: Interesting; I'll give this a whirl and let you know what happens.

Comment: I had some issues with the permissions as applied via a role, though your other idea did work out well. I created a test user without a login and adjusted the permissions until I was satisfied and then copied it to the group user. It worked like a charm, thanks!